# Lambda expression to grab all values inside a Dictionary

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have a LINQ query which returns all the values inside a Dictionary, conditional upon something:

```
var apps =
from entry in shape.Decorators
where entry.Value == DecoratorLayoutStyle.App
select entry.Key;
```

shape.Decorators is a

```
Dictionary<Shape, DecoratorLayoutStyle>
```

Is there something terser, and/or can I use a combination of lambdas or something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var apps = shape.Decorators
                .Where(x=>x.Value == DecoratorLayoutStyle.App)
                .Select(x=>x.Key);
```

I think yours is just as fine.

Answer (score 3):

That looks plenty terse to me, I guess you could use the extension functions instead of the from/select linq syntax, but that wouldn't be too different.

More imporantly, I'm not sure you ***want*** terser.  The current format is very readable, and clearly documents exactly what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

```
var apps = shape.Decorators
                     .Where(e => e.Value ==  DecoratorLayoutStyle.App)
                     .Select(e => e.Key);
```

Do you think this is terser?

Personally I prefer the query syntax when I have more than one LINQ operator all the operators I use can be translated to it.

Answer (score 1):

```
var apps = Shape.Decorators.Where(x => x.Value == DecoratorLayoutStyle.App)
                           .Select(x => x.Key);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to be different.

```
var apps = shape.Decorators.Keys
  .Where(k => shape.Decorators[k] == DecoratorLayoutStyle.App);
```